Lambda API request to Cognito is timing out
I have a NodeJS application that is trying to create users in my Cognito user pool. But this request is timing out, the response is a 504: "Request Timed Out".
My current setup is:

NodeJs v14.x
Serverless v2
Api Gateway
VPC
Lambda
Cognito

For the VPC, I have setup the Route Table for requests to "0.0.0.0/0" be routed to the NAT gateway. The NAT gateway's state is 'Available' and set to be 'Public. The Route table has associated the lambda's subnets with this route.
The Lambda has a security group attached that allows inbound & outbound requests for "0.0.0.0/0" on port 443.
The lambda role has a cognito policy attached to it, which is as follows:
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cognito-identity:*",
                "cognito-idp:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}

I am using the serverless-framework, and have set the timeout to be 60 seconds. When running this code locally, the request successfully completes in under 1-2 seconds.
In the code, I am instantiating the CognitoIdentityServiceProvider using an IAM user which also has cognito permissions of:
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "cognito-idp:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}

And the code that I am using to make the request to Cognito is as follows:
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

AWS.config.update({
  accessKeyId: ACCESS_KEY_ID,
  secretAccessKey: SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
  region: <my_aws_region>, // Replace with your AWS region
});

const cognitoIdentityServiceProvider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();

const attributeList = [
      { Name: 'name', Value: email },  
      { Name: 'email', Value: email },
      { Name: 'given_name', Value: givenName },
      { Name: "email_verified", Value: "true" },
];
    
const params = {
      UserPoolId: userPoolId, // Replace with your Cognito User Pool ID
      Username: username, // Replace with the desired username for the new user
      TemporaryPassword: password, // Replace with a temporary password for the new user
      UserAttributes: attributeList
};

try {
      const cognitoResponse = await cognitoIdentityServiceProvider.adminCreateUser(
        params
      ).promise();

      console.log('Cognito Response', JSON.stringify(cognitoResponse))

      return cognitoResponse;
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Error creating user:', err);
      throw new Error(err);
    }
}


I'm not sure if this is relevant, but the Lambda is able to successfully communicate with an RDS.
I would really appreciate any insight into why this request is timing out, thank you.
I have double checked to ensure that the Route table for external calls (0.0.0.0/0) is becoming routed to the NAT gateway. I have checked all the policies for the IAM user, Lambda Role and security group to allow traffic from port 443 to 0.0.0.0/0.
